# start and stop while loop from other part in the code using python

Tags: python, py-telegram-bot-api

I'm trying to start and stop a while loop from other parts of my python code
and it's not working well.

I'm using pyTelegramBotAPI to post some posts to my bot and it doesn't appear to be working:

```
RunPosts = True

@bot.message_handler(commands=['do','dontdo'])
def KillOrLive(message: telebot.types.Message):
    if message.text == '/do':
        RunPosts = True
        print('OK')
    elif message.text == '/dontdo':
        RunPosts = False



while RunPosts == True:
    for post in posts:
        btn = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        view = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton("Get Product", url="t.me/{}".format(post.username))
        btn.row(view)
        if post.kind == 'photo':
            bot.send_photo(admins[0],post.file_id,post.caption,reply_markup=btn)
            time.sleep(2)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: inside `KillOrLive` you have to use `global RunPosts` to inform function that it has to assing `True/False` to external/global variable `RunPosts`. Currently function creates local variable `RunPosts` which has nothing to do with global variable `RunPosts` which you use in `while` loop .

Comment: @furas i did it already as gelonida said ,. but its still not working

Comment: I also suggest to add a print("Not OK") in the elif case and a
print("callback was called") at the beginning of KillOrLive()
in the code of your question



Please post also the output of these prints.
So far we (as we can't run your script) don't even know whether the callback was called at all.

Comment: when i send '/do' command its printing to the terminal 'OK'
but the loop isnt starting

Comment: this is the output 'callback was called
OK'

Comment: but as long as you don't print the "NOT OK" case you don't have the proof that somebody didn't  it lateron again set it to False.

Don't forget, that you first loop through all posts and only then you check the condition in the while loop.

As I said I think (though I'm quite new to SO), that it is best, that your question gets at least rid of the already known problems, (so that you add the global statement) 

If not it can definitely not work and if we don't see the last code, that you tried then we don't even now whether there are any tiny details (typos) that cause the problem

Comment: please note, that I modified my answer

Comment: Please update your question with the code containing the global declaration and the print statements.

I suggest also to add one more print (e.g. print("end of loop")
Just before the line bot.polling(none_stop=True)

I'd also suggest to show is the output of the prints.

These traces and the 'global' correction are in my opinion quite important if we want to be able to help you.

Not being able to see the most recent version of the code that you tried makes it difficult to spot any sublte errors / issues.

Answer (score 0):

KillOrLive() is creating a local variable with the name RunPosts but does not change the global.

Just add the line

```
    global RunPosts
```

after the line:

```
def KillOrLive(message: telebot.types.Message):
```

You might also want to change folloing code

```
while RunPosts == True:
    for post in posts:
        btn = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        view = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton("Get Product", url="t.me/{}".format(post.username))
        btn.row(view)
        if post.kind == 'photo':
            bot.send_photo(admins[0],post.file_id,post.caption,reply_markup=btn)
            time.sleep(2)
```

to

```
while RunPosts:
    for post in posts:
        print("handling post", str(post)[:30])
        if not RunPosts:
            print("I was told to stop, so this is what I do")
            break
        btn = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        view = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton("Get Product", url="t.me/{}".format(post.username))
        btn.row(view)
        if post.kind == 'photo':
            bot.send_photo(admins[0],post.file_id,post.caption,reply_markup=btn)
            time.sleep(2)
```

if you want to stop as soon as you encountered one post, that tells you to stop

Please add also one more print for better debugging:

I suggest to replace:

```
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

with

```
print("Loop has been ended")
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: i tried that already , but its still not working :/
thats why im asking i dunno where the problem is

Comment: I suggest to correct yout code (in the question by adding the global)

Without the global it can definitely not work.

With global it should

Comment: i just added the global has you said , but its still not working sir

Comment: same attribute printing the OK but the loop is not running

Comment: I don't understand. 
Isn't this what you want? (That the loop stops running)

Perhaps you might post the output of the prints and tell where things go wrong (At which moment you would have expected another print)

Comment: I enhanced the answer with more prints.
Hopefully one of these helps to explain what's going wrong